# How do I display the next slide on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I need help. I am trying to display the next slide on the hover of the entire slider. Which means I have a product with 5 slides (1 slide is initially displayed) when I hover, I want the next slide to fade in and the pagination to be displayed (I know how to do that to display the pagination). But if, for example, I go to 3-4 slides, I want when I remove the mouse from the slider to fade in initially the first slide. I use Swiper slider and I hope someone can help me.

```
<div class="swiper-slider">
                    <div class="swiper hot-slider">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide single-product">
                                <div class="position-relative">
                                    <div class="nested-slider swiper-container">
                                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <img src="img/products/product-1.png" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <img src="img/products/product-2.png" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <img src="img/products/product-3.png" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <img src="img/products/product-1.png" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <img src="img/products/product-2.png" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <img src="img/products/product-3.png" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-child"></div>
                                        <div class="swiper-button-prev d-none d-md-block"></div>
                                        <div class="swiper-button-next d-none d-md-block"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sticker">
                                        <span>NEW</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="wishlist">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <img src="img/products/dislike.svg" alt="">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-info">
                                    <a href="#">MARILYN MONROE GREY HOODIE</a>
                                    <div class="price-info d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <div class="d-flex">
                                            <span class="regular-price d-none">75.00 €</span>
                                            <span class="old-price">75.00 €</span>
                                            <span class="sale-price">75.00 €</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="m-0">2 days left</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-scrollbar d-none d-md-block"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And my JS:

```
  if ($('.nested-slider').length > 0) {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.nested-slider', {
      loop: true,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      allowTouchMove: false,
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination-child',
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
  }
```

Don't worry that I have an hot-slider and a nested-slider because the hot-slider is the slider of all products and the nested slider is the slider of one product to which this hover question is related.